# Magento 2: How to show/hide payment method on basis of amount

Tags: magento2, php, payment-methods, magento-community, plugin

I'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.0.

I have 2 payment method Paypal Express Checkout & Bank Transfer.

When the amount is greater than X then Paypal should not be displayed only Bank Transfer.

I have configured that variable on admin side on `system.xml` for X amount.

By referring to [Magento 2 : How do we add zipcode validation on COD payment method?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135302/magento-2-how-do-we-add-zipcode-validation-on-cod-payment-method/135524#135524) as per @Ashish suggestion.

I have below code now

**app\code\Custom\Module\etc\frontend\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Paypal\Model\Express">
        <plugin sortOrder="1" name="restrictByCustomer" type="Custom\Module\Plugin\Payment\Method\Paypal\Available"/>
</type>
```

**app\code\Custom\Module\Plugin\Payment\Method\Paypal\Available.php**

```
namespace Custom\Module\Plugin\Payment\Method\Paypal;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;
use Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session as BackendSession;
use Magento\Paypal\Model\Express;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;

class Available {

    /**
     * @var CustomerSession
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * @var BackendSession
     */
    protected $backendSession;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSession $customerSession
     * @param BackendSession $backendSession
     */
    public function __construct(
    CustomerSession $customerSession, BackendSession $backendSession, ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig, Cart $cart
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->backendSession = $backendSession;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->cart = $cart;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param Paypal Express $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return bool
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function afterIsAvailable(Express $subject, $result) {

        // Do not remove payment method for admin
        if ($this->backendSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            return $result;
        }

        $cartQuote = $this->cart->getQuote()->getData();
        $cartGrandTotal = $cartQuote['base_grand_total'];

        list($grandTotal, $decimals) = explode(".", $cartQuote['base_grand_total']);
        $papalMaxShowLimit = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('mygeneral/settings/paypal_show_amount', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

        if ($grandTotal > $papalMaxShowLimit) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I have put all condition. But on `return false` it's not hiding Paypal Express Checkout Method.

**[Update] I'm not able select Paypal Payment Method's Radio Button On Checkout Page. It's not hiding it completely.**

Comment: Hi SO Community, Please guide me to achieve functionality. Thanks

Comment: Guys less than 1 day left please try to help if u can. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/130466/1883 , https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/180422/1883

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Paypal\Model\Express" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Express" />
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Express.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class Express extends \Magento\Paypal\Model\Express 
{

    public function isAvailable(\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null)
    {
    ...........Write your own logic here and reture true/false on basis of ................     
    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Things which u have mentioned all are in Question

Comment: Now check my updated answer.

Comment: Nope still now working only putting `return false;` then also it's Displaying Paypal Checkout

Comment: Which paypal method you are using ? This is for paypal express checkout and its working for me.

Comment: Yes it's Paypal Express Checkout. It's not working for Me don't know why.

Comment: Check it in default Magento once. Also try module upgrade and compilation once

Comment: On Server Working Fine. Great Job. Thanks a lot :) Here you go

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to resolve this :

[Magento 2 : How do we add zipcode validation on COD payment method?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135302/magento-2-how-do-we-add-zipcode-validation-on-cod-payment-method/135524#135524)

in this example just replace the class `Cashondelivery` with your payment method class on which you want to add filter.

In this example

```
public function afterIsAvailable(Cashondelivery $subject, $result)
{
// Do not remove payment method for admin
if ($this->backendSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    return $result;
}
   ......return true/false according to your condition.......

return true/false;

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashish. Where should i put condition to check?

Comment: @AnkitShah, Pl check my updated answer.

Comment: Ok. Means I need to put the condition on Paypal Express Checkout. Let me check @Ashish & revert.

Comment: Hi @Ashish it's not hiding my Paypal Method. So updated code in question. Thanks

Comment: @AnkitShah, Have you used Paypal Express class path instead of Cashondelivery class path of default Magento class properly ?

Comment: Yes. It's correct checked

Comment: Code is ok @Ashish. Please check updated question. on `return false` it's not hiding PayPal method. Don't know why?

Comment: Hey @Ashish. It's not working as expected. Can help me out?

Comment: Hey @Ashish. It's still not working as expected. Can help me out?

Comment: Any luck guys? Still facing issue

Comment: [Update] By Doing this I'm only not able select Payment Method Paypal's Radio Button On Checkout Page. It's not hiding it completely.

Comment: Any help or updates?

Comment: @AnkitShah, Whats the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have solved by overiding Paypal Express Model

In you `di.xml` file

```
<preference for="Magento\Paypal\Model\Express" type="Custom\Module\Model\Express" />
```

In Your **app\code\Custom\Module\Model\Express.php**

```
namespace Custom\Module\Model;

class Express extends \Magento\Paypal\Model\Express {

    public function isAvailable(\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null) {

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $cart = $objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
        $scopeConfig = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface');

        if (isset($cart)) {
            $grandTotal = $cart->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
            if (!empty($grandTotal)) {
                list($grandTotal, $decimals) = explode(".", $grandTotal);

                if ($grandTotal > XXXX) { #Replace XXXX with Amount Say 1000/10
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```