# Magento 2: Load Payment Method while Checkout using Event Observer

Tags: magento2, checkout, event-observer, payment-methods, custom

I have referred all  Event's list

https://cyrillschumacher.com/magento2-list-of-all-dispatched-events/

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-events.html

I have below issue

[Magento 2: How to show/hide payment method on basis of amount](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137738/magento-2-how-to-show-hide-payment-method-on-basis-of-amount)

Can i manage through Event Observer? If Yes then what will be name? I'm not able to find on above links

```
<event name="controller_action_predispatch_XXXX_XXX_index">
        <observer name="check_checkout_page" instance="Custom\Module\Observer\MyObserver" />
</event>
```

When user on http://localhost/magento2/checkout/ before it loads payment method i would like to call my observer.