# Magento 2: Unable to Get Cart Information

Tags: magento2, cart, quote

In addition of [Magento 2: How to show/hide payment method on basis of amount](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137738/magento-2-how-to-show-hide-payment-method-on-basis-of-amount)

Below code i have

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class Express extends \Magento\Paypal\Model\Express {

    public function isAvailable(\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null) {
        $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        $quote = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
        $quoteitems = $quote->getQuote()->getData();

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($quoteitems);
        exit;
    }
}
```

**Output**

Array

```
(
    [is_checkout_cart] => 1
    [store_id] => 1
    [remote_ip] => ::1
    [x_forwarded_for] => 
)
```

It's not giving my any Cart related information, Items, Base Total, Grand Total, etc..

Also referred http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-useful-snippets-for-frontend-developers also not working

If i put any kind of `Constructor` it's not allowing me to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with below code,

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface as QuoteItemRepository;


class Express extends \Magento\Paypal\Model\Express 
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        QuoteItemRepository $quoteItemRepository
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->quoteItemRepository = $quoteItemRepository;
    }

    public function isAvailable(\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null)
    {
       echo "<pre>";print_r($quote->debug());

        //return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not getting `$quoteId` it's Blank

Comment: Hi @Rakesh any advise??

Comment: Try with updated answer.

Comment: It's not showing anything. Only blank page.

Comment: Have you checked $quote->getStoreId() to display anything?

Comment: Still it shows blank page with No Data display. If i comment constructor then page is loading full otherwise not with `return false`. I think issue may be we are extending Paypal Model Express that's why we don't able to so much over here. I'm also not able to Store Config Variable value over herer

Comment: Hi @Rakesh any suggestion?

Comment: HI @Rakesh any updates?

Comment: This code is not working for me.

Comment: For some reason `\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface` returns null for `getItems` or `getItemsCount` even if I have items in cart.