# magento 2 payment methods hide by code

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

How to hide PayPal Express Checkout in code at the following location:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml

```
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
```

[image: preview]

How to debug this `ko`.?

Case:

Express checkout is enabled at admin. Example:

- product sku: *commission-product*
- if *commission-product* is added to cart: payment through Express checkout
- else: show all payment methods expect Express checkout

Comment: Are you want to remove paypal express checkout payment method?

Comment: yes but with code http://prntscr.com/fn5bf7

Comment: you can turn off from admin , else hide via css

Comment: yes but i want to hide by code.

Comment: this has no specific class to display none http://prntscr.com/fn5uhl or if we hide by css nth child, if any other payment added issue will be there

Comment: Why? Please provide some details, what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Express checkout is enabled at admin.
Example sku product: commission-product

If commission-product is added to cart-->payment through Express checkout
else show all payment methods expect Express checkout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a plugin:

> Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- Plugins -->
    <type name="Magento\Paypal\Model\Express">
        <plugin name="disable_paypal_express"
                type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\DisablePayPalExpress"
                sortOrder="10"
                disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> Vendor/Module/Plugin/DisablePayPalExpress.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class DisablePayPalExpress
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session|\Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote
     */
    protected $session;

    /** List of the skus for which this method should be disabled */
    protected $disabledForSku = [
        'commission-product',
        'another-sku',
        'Gloves'
    ];

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote $backendQuoteSession
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote $backendQuoteSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
    ) {
        if ($state->getAreaCode() == \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML) {
            $this->session = $backendQuoteSession;
        } else {
            $this->session = $checkoutSession;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Paypal\Model\Express $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return bool
     */
    public function afterIsAvailable(
        \Magento\Paypal\Model\Express $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $this->session->getQuote();
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item[] $quoteItems */
        $quoteItems = $quote->getAllItems();
        foreach ($quoteItems as $quoteItem) {
            if (in_array($quoteItem->getSku(), $this->disabledForSku)) {
                return false; // disable the method if we found product with specified sku
            }
        }

        return $result; // return default result
    }
}
```

If you return false, method should be always disabled. If you need a custom validation, just add it in the methods body and use a desired result.

Comment: @EwallTester I've updated my answer based on your comments to the question (disable method if specific sku is found in the cart)

Comment: @EwallTester I'm glad to help you :)

Comment: hi I have a issue here Siarhey

Comment: @EwallTester which issue?

Comment: From the code, For the first time if the product sku: commission-product is added or not Express checkout should be disabled, and if commission-product is in cart only Express checkout should be shown and all other should be disabled

Comment: currently as per the code all payments are showing and if commission-product is added then only Express checkout is visible and braintree also is shown

Comment: Available Payment methods:
Paypal Barin Tree,
Express checkout, and
check/money order.

By default: Express checkout should be invisible
If product sku: commission-product is added then it should show only Express checkout

Comment: please find the latest comment and please help me on this

Comment: @EwallTester for your purpose you should write a plugin for each method which you are using, and you should disable or enable them based on the cart items (as in my answer).

Comment: ok will try to write plugins for each method.. and get back to you if any.thanks

Comment: Hi @Siarhey, can you help me on this issue
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186375/
why-my-order-missing-ship-hold-creditmemo-and-sendmail