# Why my order missing ship, hold, creditmemo and sendmail

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

I have a order that is in status processing but issue is i cannot find these buttons missing ship, hold, creditmemo and sendmail, please find the below link.

[image]

This is only for some products in order. But iam unable to find the issue and unable to find the difference between product which are ship and not-shipable.

can anyone help me on this issue. thanks

Comment: Could you share a full order view screenshot?

Comment: ok just a minute

Comment: please find my updated question , you can find the full screenshot thanks

Comment: Is your product in stock? Maybe this product is just backordered and can't be shipped because there is not enough stock items.

Comment: our code is----if the product has 0 or less than 0 then it will display backorder

Comment: and every day a cron runs -- it will process the backorder status to processing if the stock is now greater than 0

Comment: now the stock is 920 for that product

Answer (score 1):

I cant say something about a custom code, but first try to check what happens in the base order methods like:

- `canCreditmemo()`
- `canShip()`
- etc.

in the class `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` (`app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php`)

because all buttons adds in the block-class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View` (`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View.php`) and each of them has an own conditions. If conditions do not met - button is hidden, and vice versa.

Comment: ok thanks but only some of the orders having this issue

Comment: @EwallTester Write in the block file something like `var_dump($this->_isAllowedAction('emails'));
        var_dump(!$order->isCanceled());
        die();` before the line `if ($this->_isAllowedAction('emails') && !$order->isCanceled()) {` then refresh the page with your "broken" order and check a result. There is two cases: 1) Not enough permissions 2) Order is canceled. If all vardums show `true` your button should be shown (when you remove this code).  If this is not the case, then most likely the problem is with the third-party module that overwrites the block.

Comment: in which file should keep this

Comment: @EwallTester block file is located in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View.php`

Comment: ok i will keep this update the result..thanks

Comment: bool(true) bool(false)  this is the result

Comment: @EwallTester This result means that your orders is canceled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62846/discussion-between-ewall-tester-and-siarhey-uchukhlebau).