# How to show "custom message" in payment section when COD disable for particular product Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, messages, cash-on-delivery

I followed the steps in the below link to disable COD for a particular product.

[magento 2 payment methods hide by code](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180422/magento-2-payment-methods-hide-by-code).

But I need to show a custom message(**some of the items in the cart are not eligible for COD**) in the payment section, when COD gets disabled. How can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't post your code, I am not able to help you, but here is the simple method to display a custom message in Magento 2.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
   require(['jquery','Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'], function($, customerData){
     $.ajax({
      //your code
     success: function(data)
     {
          var yourmsg = msg+' '+wishlist_link;
          customerData.set('messages', {
               messages: [{
                     type: 'success', //user as per your need
                     text: yourmsg
                        }]
           });
     }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Magento 1 => https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/302345/57334  any help thanks @Sagar Parikh SGR